# How would I wrap a div that is repeating in a .map method

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, loops, jsx

How do I wrap one of my returns in a .map function in a single containing div?

I know I could wrap the entire .map in a div however I have two different returns in the .map because I have a a if statement that is checking if a graphQL typename exists. My issue is I want to wrap the outputs of `<BlockGridWrapper>` in a parent div that wraps the entire output of divs so I can use display grid on them. I could do it if I didn't have the if statement with two different returns in the .map, since I dont want to wrap the `<NewBlock>` just the `<BlockGridWrapper>`

Here is my map

```
 {data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock.map(projectEntry => { 

      if (projectEntry.__typename === 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent') {
        return (
          <NewBlock key={projectEntry.id}> 

             Text Here

        </NewBlock>

        )
      }
      else{

        return (  // I want every div outputted here to be wrapped in one containing div

          <>

          <BlockGridWrapper>
            <BlockGrid key={projectEntry.id}>  
                <div>{projectEntry.titleOfGridSection}</div>
                <Img fluid={projectEntry.imageOfGridBlock.fluid} /> 
            </BlockGrid>
          </BlockGridWrapper>

          </>
        )

      }

  })}
```

The outputed html looks like below, I need the div's wrapped in one container div

[image]

Here is my query for what the data I am getting it from

```
projectBlock{
        __typename
        ... on DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent { //this is NewBLock
            id
            titleOfSection
            descriptionOfImage
            descriptionToggle
            wideView
            imageTextSide
            imageAssetHideShow
            imageAsset{
              url
              originalId
            }
          }
        ... on DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid { //This is BlockGridWrapper
          id
          titleOfGridSection
          imageOfGridBlock {
            fluid(maxWidth:400) {
              ...GatsbyDatoCmsFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

So I want it in the end to be formated like below

```
<div>
  blockgridwrapper,
  blockgridwrapper
</div>
newblock,
<div>
  blockgridwrapper
</div>
newblock,
newblock,
newblock,
<div>
  blockgridwrapper,
  blockGridwrapper,
  blockGridwrapper
</div>
```

**For Moinuls second answer here is my response**

So as per the same answer here is the console.log of the wrapped data

```
0: Array(3)
0: {__typename: "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent", id: "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent-2018663-en", titleOfSection: "About Mussels", descriptionOfImage: "<h1><b>Heading 1</b></h1><p><span style="font-weig…DO: Anders and Riel Style</span></p></blockquote>", descriptionToggle: true, …}
1: {__typename: "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent", id: "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent-2018670-en", titleOfSection: "Test Title on top", descriptionOfImage: "<h1><b>Heading 1</b></h1><p><span style="font-weig…can see a list of things we did below.</span></p>", descriptionToggle: true, …}
2: {__typename: "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent", id: "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent-2018672-en", titleOfSection: "", descriptionOfImage: "", descriptionToggle: true, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
1: Array(4)
0: {__typename: "DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid", id: "DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid-2043741-en", titleOfGridSection: "Test", imageOfGridBlock: {…}}
1: {__typename: "DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid", id: "DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid-2043742-en", titleOfGridSection: "Test #2", imageOfGridBlock: {…}}
2: {__typename: "DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid", id: "DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid-2043743-en", titleOfGridSection: "Test #3", imageOfGridBlock: {…}}
3: {__typename: "DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid", id: "DatoCmsProjectBlockGrid-2043744-en", titleOfGridSection: "Test #4", imageOfGridBlock: {…}}
```

now if I do the nested map with this code below

```
wrappedData.map(list => {
        return (
          <div>
            {list.map(l =>
              l._typeName === "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent" ? (
                <NewBlock >text1</NewBlock>
              ) : (
                <BlockGridWrapper>
                  text2
                </BlockGridWrapper>
              )
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })
```

I get the following html output, however it is showing `<BLockGridWrapper>` twice when it should show `<NewBlock>` based on the ternary operator typeName check. Where I have circled should be NewBlock with text 1 content instead of text2 content . Otherwise We are very close to the result I wanted. As long as it can handle them coming in different order, not just in a row, when I test in the cms.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I guess you can create an array of array of contiguous elements and then run loop over them. something like

```
const wrap = data => {
  const res = [[data[0]]];
  let curr = data[0];
  // let curr = 0;
  let idx = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].__typename === curr.__typename) {
      res[idx].push(data[i]);
    } else {
      curr = data[i];
      idx += 1;
      res[idx] = [curr];
    }
  }
};

const wrappedData = wrap(data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock);

/* wrappedData will look like (maintaining the order)

[ 
  [
  {__typename: 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent',...},
  {__typename: 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent',...},
  {__typename: 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent',...},
  ], 
  [
    {__typename: 'NotDatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent'},
    {__typename: 'NotDatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent'},
    {__typename: 'NotDatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent'}
  ],
  [ 
    {__typename: 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent',...},
    {__typename: 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent',...},
  ],
  // and so on
]




*/


Now in your render you gotta do a nested loop:


wrappedData.map(list => {
  return (
    <div>
      {list.map(l =>
        l._typeName === "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent" ? (
          <NewBLock />
        ) : (
          <BlockWrapper />
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: for the first part I tried console logging the wrappedData and I am getting undefined, I put the code inside my component `const IndexPage = ({data}) => {` before the return

Comment: and when I console log whats in the wrap it has all my data `console.log(data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock);`

Comment: I added the output of the console log to see if that would help debug why when I use the wrap function put it in a variable and console log that variable I get undefined.

Comment: Oh I think I needed to return the `res` inside the function now I am getting the array in the array with the data. Ok gonna try the second part now

Comment: Ok so for some reason it is outputting the <blockWrapper> in when the `<NewBlock>` should be outputting I will add a screenshot of the outputted html above.

Comment: So When I console.log `console.log(l.__typeName)` I get undefined 7 times, so I think there is something incorrect in the nested loop, I changed `l._typeName` to `l.__typeName` as it is in the data but still nothing. hmm...

Comment: weird when I console.log just `console.log(l)` I get all the data. Hmm...

Comment: lowercase `typename` got it now, Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with all the NewBlock components above all the BlockGridWrapper components, then this should work. If you don't want the NewBlock components interspersed, then you should wrap groups of consecutive BlockGridWrapper components.

You can either do this:

```
let newBlockArr = [];
let blockgridArr = [];
data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock.forEach(v => {
  if (v.__typename === 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent') {
    newBlockArr.push( <NewBlock key={v.id}>Text Here</NewBlock> );
  } else {
    blockGridArr.push(
      <BlockGridWrapper>
        <BlockGrid key={v.id}>  
          <div>{projectEntry.titleOfGridSection}</div>
          <Img fluid={v.imageOfGridBlock.fluid} /> 
        </BlockGrid>
      </BlockGridWrapper>
    );
  }
});
```

or this:

```
let newBlockArr = data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock.filter(v => v.__typename === 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent').map(v => ( <NewBlock key={v.id}>Text Here</NewBlock> ));
let blockgridArr = data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock.filter(v => v.__typename !== 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent').map(v => (
  <BlockGridWrapper>
    <BlockGrid key={v.id}>  
      <div>{projectEntry.titleOfGridSection}</div>
      <Img fluid={v.imageOfGridBlock.fluid} /> 
    </BlockGrid>
  </BlockGridWrapper>
));
```

Followed by:

```
return (
  <div>{newBlockArr}</div>
  <div>{blockgridArr}</div>
);
```

Comment: I want the BlockGridWrapper componenets to come as they are entered in the cms, so it could go [newblock, blockgridwrapper, blockgridwrapper, newblock] so on.. .does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an if else, so your `BlockGridWrapper`s won't be continuously available in the array. Your mapped array could look something like

```
[
 <BlockGridWrapper ... ,
 <BlockGridWrapper ...,
 < NewBlock ...,
 <BlockGridWrapper...

]
```

In that case how are you going to have a div around the `BlockGridWrapper`s since you have a `NewBlock` in between?

I don't know your use case but you could either partition the array into two containing the `NewBlock`s into one and the `BlockGridWrapper`s into another.

```
const newBlocks = data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock.filter(projectEntry => projectEntry.__typename === 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent')

const notNewBlocks = data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock.filter(projectEntry => projectEntry.__typename !== 'DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent')


return (
   <WhateverYourComponentIs>
       ...

      {newBlocks.map(projectEntry =><NewBlock key={projectEntry.id}></NewBlock> )}
      <div>{notNewBlocks.map(projectEntry => <BlockGridWrapper>...</BlockGridWrapper> )}</div>

   </<WhateverYourComponentIs

)
```

Comment: Now with separating the maps, they won't necessarily come in order they are all in one query in graphQL so I need them to come in the order they are entered in the cms. I will add my query above. With your solution I think It will have all the Newblocks come in a row and then all the Notnewblocks, but it should alternate if it is in that order in the cms, depending. I will add my query above if it helps you understand my use case

Comment: are you saying that all your BlockGridWrapper elements would appear in a row if they do? Something like `NewBlock,NewBlock , NewBlock, BlockGridWrapper, BlockGridWrapper, BlockGridWrapper, NewBlock, NewBlock, NewBlock,BlockGridWrapper, BlockGridWrapper, ` and so on?

Comment: yep exactly, its all variable because both are being entered from a cms

Comment: hmm maybe Im not explaining right. I want it to be able to go `blockGridWrapper, newBlock, newBlock, blockGridWrapper...` whatever order they are entered in the cms is the order they should appear in the page.

Comment: but a blockGridWrapper beginning and end should always have a wrapping and closing div, so if it would look like this      `<div>blockgridwrapper,blockgridwrapper</div>newblock,<div>blockgridwrapper</div>newblock,newblock,newblock,<div>blockgridwrapper,blockGridwrapper,blockGridwrapper</div>`